# Publish a page on pages list using Workflow on SP2013 Online

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

The Workflow has the option to check in a file, but I can't see the option to publish it.

It is a `site Workflow`.
I have use the POST method with the `type:SP.Data.PagesItem` like in the post on the link in [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/828c57ef-9bd7-4ca9-aaa1-6a74532461d3/odatamoderationstatus-http-web-service-post-sp2013?forum=sharepointdevelopment). And using the url:

```
 http://siteCollection/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Pages')/items?$select=Id,Title,OData__ModerationStatus&$filter=Title eq 'myTitle'
```

And updating the property: `OData__ModerationStatus` to `0`.
The first problems I had was the both bellow:

```
{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The property 'X-HTTP-Method' does not exist on type 'SP.Data.PagesItem'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type."}}}

{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The property 'IF-MATCH' does not exist on type 'SP.Data.PagesItem'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type."}}}
```

After removing the both header properties I have got the error:

```
{"error":{"code":"-2146232832, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"To add an item to a document library, use SPFileCollection.Add()"}}}
```

It was thinking I wanted to add a new element.

So I have tried removing those two properties, but called the method using `PUT`.
And I have got the errors:

```
{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The type SP.ListItemEntityCollection does not support HTTP PUT method."}}}
```

I just need to publish a page using workflows, does anybody have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer for this question.
The Url I was calling is wrong. There is a [REST API for publishing a page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246112.aspx).

So you need to create a Web Service Call on the Workflow, make a `POST` without any request parameters, even without the `__metadata` property that usually is used. But with the request headers filled in as:

```
Accept: application/json;odata=verbose
Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose
```

And the new Url would be.

```
https://site/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Pages')/files/getbyurl('myFileName.aspx')/publish('Published by the Workflow')
```